# PHP function inside a string without the dot operator

Tags: php, php-7.2

I am using raw PHP as a templating system for a small project.

So far, the following code has been working very well for me:

```
$output = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
 elit. Morbi id pharetra nunc.{$someVariable} imperdiet, libero eget
 {$someVariable2} molestie mattis non vel nunc. Cras maximus enim eu dolor
 {$someVariable3} venenatis et sed nibh. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
 consectetur adipiscing elit.";
```

However, I need to use functions inside the string I am building. Is there a way to call a function from inside the string without having to use the dot operators to concatenate?

So, something like:

```
$output = "that was {functionhere('easypeasy')}";
```

instead of:

```
$output = "that was " . functionhere('easypeasy');
```

Much like what frameworks like Angular allow you to do.

Comment: Kindly mention which PHP version you are using?

Comment: Why not just use the standard notation?

Comment: I am using PHP 7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this one.

```
function fname() { 
    return 'Hi'; 
} 
$my_fname= 'fname';      
echo "{$my_fname()}";
```

Comment: Perfect. This is really helpful.